# Sql, trying to sum values up to a specific value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem where I have a large count of values on one side(a) and need to sum themup to a single value on the other(x) . There is no logical grouping to get to the total value(x)

On side (a) there are 10000+ items that need to be summed to a single value on the (z) side. Not all of the values on side (a) are needed to sum up to (z)

```
(a)                 (z) 
123.                2
321.                19
234.                100
122
1
23
1
19
77
```

Expected output:

```
(a) 1, 1.     = (z) 2
(a) 19.       = (z) 19
(a) 23, 77.   = (z) 100
```

Sum(a) to equal a value in (z)

My current code groups on date but now that will not work as I do not have a predefined date range.

Current code:

```
Select * From
(
    Select sum(amount), date
    From (a)
    Group by date
) a
Inner join 
(
    Select amount,date
    From (z)
) b on a.date = b.date
Where a.Amount - b.Amount = 0
```

Comment: Some sample data and expected output would be useful

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Sorry guys I have no access from my desktop so I am typing all this from my phone.

Comment: What is the logic or reason that makes `1` and `1` go together? What makes `19` be treated as a single value, and why do `23` and `77` go together? Finally why are `123`, `321` (etc) ignored / skipped?

Comment: On side (a) there are a lot of payments from individuals. On side (z) are the deposits made. The payments are summed to the values irrespective of the date received as an amount for a product can be received on the first day and then again on the 9th day but only deposited on the 11th day. Payments can be captured without being deposited as of yet

Comment: So you mean that **(z)** is an **input** table for which matching values from **(a)** need to be found and added? Please specify as clear as you can what the algorithm should do, preferrably by [editing the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52985169/edit). And show what you have tried to solve it yourself, because Stack Overflow is not a write-my-code-for-me service.

Comment: I have the fields Amount and Date, currently code matches the 2 sides on date and amount.

Comment: That doesn't sound like something I would do in SQL at all. You'd build all combinations from a where the sum matches some value in z. Then you'd look which matches to apply so most (or all?) z are satisfied. E.g. with a = 2,3,4,5,6 and z=7,8, you'll find that 2+5 match 7 and 3+4 match 7 and 3+5 match 8 and 2+6 match 8. So you'd best pick 3+4=7 and 2+6=8, because thus you match both z values, which is not possible with the other pairs, because they are competing for values. With more numbers (1+2+4+6=13, and 2+5+6=13 and 6+7=13 ...) this will get quite complex.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a self-join:

```
select z.z, a1.amount, a2.amount
from z z left join
     (a a1 left join
      a a2
      on a1.amount < a2.amount
     )
     on z.amount = a1.amount + coalesce(a2.amount, 0);
```